# My Neural Network doesn't recognize one type of label in a vector label

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, multilabel-classification

So I have this problem where a detect if something is wrong in different nodes across a water distribution system. I created a neural network that has water pressure across the system as input and has a vector as an output. The vector size is the same as the number of nodes in the system and if the entire vector is at 0 it means there is nothing wrong, but if one of the elements has an 1 it means that node has something wrong with it. So far so good. The problem is when I train the algorithm and when I trace the confusion matrix I noticed that the algorithm doesn't even consider the cases when all of the vector is at 0. Does anyone know how to fix this? Should I just delete the data that has nothing wrong in any node?

```
self.X=self.data.values
self.y=self.labels
    
        
self.transformer = preprocessing.QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='uniform').fit(self.X)
self.X_normalized = self.transformer.transform(self.X)
self.data_normalized = pd.DataFrame(self.X_normalized)
self.data_normalized.columns = self.data.columns

self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(self.data_normalized,                    self.labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=6)

 self.y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(self.y_train.values)
 self.y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(self.y_test.values)
```

I tried to reshape the output to have 25 labels instead of 24(the number of nodes is 24)

```
self.model.add(Dense(25*2, activation=self.config['algorithm']['out_activation']))
                                                         
self.model.add(Reshape((25,2)))
```

But it returns this error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 24, 2) and (None, 25, 2) are incompatible
```

Comment: I think you have the wrong learning setup, one-hot encoding your labels means one class will always be predicted, which does not match your "the algorithm doesn't even consider the cases when all of the vector is at 0". What you want is multi-label classification, not multi-class.